# Prototype design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

As a practice and self-development exercise I have decided to implement design patterns in C#.

I am using polish cuisine as an example in my implementations. In this project I implemented Prototype design pattern.

Model:

```
public static class PierogiTypes
{
    public const string WithPotatoesAndCheese = "with potatoes and cheese";
    public const string WithGroat = "with groat";
    public const string WithCabbage = "with cabbage";
    public const string WithMeat = "with meat";
    public const string WithStrawberries = "with strawberries";
    public const string WithBlueberries = "with blueberries";
    public const string WithPotatoesAndCheeseButAlsoWithYoghurtAndKetchup = "with potatoes and cheese but also with yoghurt and ketchup";
}
```

Desgin Pattern:

```
using Creational.Prototype.Model;

namespace Creational.Prototype.DesignPatters;

public abstract class PierogiPrototype
{
    public Guid Guid { get; }
    public int Count { set; get; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    
    public PierogiPrototype(int count)
    {
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Count = count;
    }
    
    public abstract PierogiPrototype Clone();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Guid: {Guid}, Count: {Count}, Type: {Type}";
    }
}

public class PierogiWithPotatoesAndCheese : PierogiPrototype
{
    public PierogiWithPotatoesAndCheese(int count) : base(count)
    {
        Type = PierogiTypes.WithPotatoesAndCheese;
    }

    public override PierogiPrototype Clone()
    {
        return (PierogiPrototype)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

.
.
.
.
.

public class PierogiWithBlueberries : PierogiPrototype
{
    public PierogiWithBlueberries(int count) : base(count)
    {
        Type = PierogiTypes.WithBlueberries;
    }

    public override PierogiPrototype Clone()
    {
        return (PierogiPrototype)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Program:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var firstPortion = new PierogiWithBlueberries(10);
        Console.WriteLine(firstPortion);
        var secondPortion = firstPortion.Clone();
        Console.WriteLine(secondPortion);
        firstPortion.Count = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(firstPortion);
        Console.WriteLine(secondPortion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem scope

- The prototype design pattern is usually used whenever you want to minimize the creation time and/or resources of a complex or costly object

  - Complex: it has several nested data structures (in other words it is a data rich object)
  - Costly: either from time or resource (like CPU or I/O) perspective (like using network/database calls to retrieve initial values)
- According to my understanding none of the above can be said about your derived classes of the `PierogiPrototype`

### Shallow or Deep copy

- The `MemberwiseClone` method performs a [shallow copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-7.0) which means only the top-level properties are copied over

  - In case of a complex object you want to copy all the nested structures as well not just their references
- I'm unsure that you are aware of the [`ICloneable` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-7.0) but it might make sense to take a look at it

### Registry or Catalogue

- [The prototype pattern can be extended](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/prototype) in a way that there is a central place where you store the prototypes and from where you can create copies
- In your case you could store all the variants and create a copy by using the `Type` string

Comment: Thank you for your comment Peter. Its pleasure to meet you again :D. I am making this simple projects as proof of concepts/commemoration exercises. Those might indeed be too simple and exactly fulfill typical use cases. Nevertheless I am more than greateful for your insights. I am fully aware of ICloneable and deep copy/shallow copy mechanisms but in this particular example there is no difference between them. I will keep this one simple and bear in mind the need of deep copy when necessary. Your material to prototype pattern is very interesting, I will make adjustments based on it :D

Comment: Hi @Artur, nice to meet you again :). I think it is pretty hard to find a simple, yet repsentative prototype candidate. Like I said this pattern should be used against costly or complex objects. If the data structure does not meet either of the criteria then the pattern feels a bit overkill for that problem.